# How can I display array elements passed as a prop to functional component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I have created `amenitiesArray` which has elements like club_house, swimming_pool, etc. I am mapping over this `amenitiesArray` using `.map()` but when I pass it as a prop I am not able to display it on screen why so?

`console.log(amenitiesArray)` is:

```
0:"Gymnasium"
1:"swimming_pool"
2:"club_house"
3:"childrens_play_area"
4:"multipurpose_room"
5:"security"
6:"jogging_track"
7:"power_backup"
8:"landscaped_gardens"
9:"car_parking"
```

Code:

```
const DisplayAmenities = ({ name }) => (
  <Text style={{ color: 'black', fontSize: 16 }}>{name}</Text>
);

export default class Project extends Component {
  render() {
    let amenitiesArray = [];

    for (var key in amenities[0]) {
      if (amenities[0][key] === 'Yes') {
        amenitiesArray.push(key);
      }
    }
    console.log(amenitiesArray);

    return (
      <ScrollView>
        <View style={{ marginTop: 20 }}>
          {amenitiesArray.map(val => {
            <DisplayAmenities name={val} />;
          })}
        </View>
      </ScrollView>
    );
  }
}
```

Above code does not display anything on screen? Why so?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you forgot to return the component. Try to fix like this:

```
 return (
      <ScrollView>
        <View style={{ marginTop: 20 }}>
          {amenitiesArray.map((val,index) => {
            return <DisplayAmenities key={index} name={val} />;  //fixed
          })}
        </View>
      </ScrollView>
    );
```

For short, you could omit the curly brackets, like so

```
 return (
      <ScrollView>
        <View style={{ marginTop: 20 }}>
          {amenitiesArray.map((val,index) => <DisplayAmenities key={index} name={val} /> )}
        </View>
      </ScrollView>
    );
```

Comment: @Nguyen Thanks it works but it gives warning key should be unique how can I fix that ?

Comment: I've updated my answer! In this case, we might use the `index` as the `key` for each component

Comment: @NguyễnThanhTú Why index if you can use something more meaningful? There's `val` already

Comment: @estus yeah, sure! For a good practice, we should use a `stable` identifier such as `id`. For instance, it should be something like `key={ val.id }`

Answer (score 1):

```
  {amenitiesArray.map(val => {
    <DisplayAmenities name={val} />;
  })}
```

lacks explicit return, `map` callback function maps an array to an array of `undefined`.

For implicit arrow return, it should be:

```
  {amenitiesArray.map(val => 
    <DisplayAmenities name={val} />;
  )}
```

The use of [`array-callback-return` ESLint rule](https://eslint.org/docs/rules/array-callback-return) allows to avoid this sort of mistakes.